# How can error_reporting be overridden?

Tags: php, error-reporting

I have set `error_reporting = 0` in php.ini, but when I create a script containing `<?php echo "error: ".error_reporting(); ?>` it reports an error level of 7. What else could be setting the error_reporting value?

Comment: Solved: turns out I had an .htaccess redirect to a script which would set the error_reporting and then include the original file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many places this can be set that override the main `php.ini`.  Run `phpinfo()` and check *Local Value*    and *Master Value* for error_reporting.  Also check to see if any of the following exist and if they have a different setting for error_reporting:

- Loaded Configuration File (make sure this is the php.ini file that you edited)
- Additional .ini files parsed
- CUSTOM_PHP_INI
- Any .htaccess (if using Apache)

Any of the above can override settings in the Loaded Configuration File `php.ini`.

Comment: Thanks. I've checked these, and none of them contain error_reporting. Anywhere else it might be?

Comment: Ok, this didn't solve my specific problem, but it answers the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

It could be set within PHP with `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);`

Btw. Are you sure you're loading correct php.ini file? Check it with phpinfo();

Comment: I know, but my file literally contains only `<?php echo "error: ".error_reporting(); ?>`, so it must be being set somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If you have modified directly the php.ini, and i'm guessing you're using apache, you must have to restart it for your changes take effect.

All right, restarted and not working ? you can try set it by using a pure PHP code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Comment: I did restart after modifying it. If I put a call to error_reporting in the code, then yes I can change it; but why is it initially different from the ini file?

Comment: What is the return of `echo ini_get('error_reporting');` ?